# System class loader in Play Framework 2

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, classloader

I'm using Play 2.2.2, and I have an external jar that tries to load an XML resource from the same jar's root. It does so using `System.class.getClassLoader().getResource("/Blabla.xml")`.
This fails, since apparently Play has a weird hierarchy of classloaders: ReloadableClassLoader and several parents. This hierarchy doesn't include the system class loader, nor the extensions and bootstrap classloaders.

How is this possible?

I found out that using ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader() returns a classloader hierarchy that resembles the standard classloading hierarchy. But I would prefer not to touch the external jar mentioned above, and make `System.class.getClassLoader().getResource("/Blabla.xml")` work.

How can I make `System.class.getClassLoader().getResource("/Blabla.xml")` return the standard system classloader?

Answer (score 0):

Play's classloader set-up is rather complex due to the compile-reload mechanism in development mode. Rather than trying to use the normal `System.class.getClassLoader()` you may want to use [built-in API methods](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/java/play/Application.html#resource%28java.lang.String%29) to get to a resource or to the classloader.